# How do I implement a custom (floorplan image) map in an iOS app..?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

Some examples of apps which implement this are..

1. [Yorkdale App](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/yorkdale/id356097704?mt=8)
2. [Icon Brickell](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icon-brickell/id397604696?mt=8)

I am a beginner, and have implemented MKMapView.

I am not understanding how do I begin..

Thanks for your precious guidance..!

Comment: I need to present a floor plan, with ability to drop pins on it (to mark the stores). Also, I need to be able to zoom and pan the floor plan, with the pins intact..

Comment: You would have thought that in the 5 months you have been a member here you would have taken 2 minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) We are not here to do your work for you. Go and think about it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Those kind of implementations has nothing to do with the KMMapView. Please refer to the iOs developer documentation: [Location Awareness Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html)

> A map view contains a flattened representation of a spherical object, namely the Earth. In order to use maps effectively, you need to understand a little bit about how to specify points in a map view, and how those points translate to points on the Earth’s surface.

I would suggest you to create a custom view based on UIScrollView with the corresponding images (UIImage). You can make map-like annotations by creating custom views and attaching them to your view as sub-views as needed.

Comment: I have scrollview with map image.plus have lat long value of its top left and end bottom right and now i want to put pin between region.but its not set as same as google can you please suggest something.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a plain `UIScrollview` containing the map image with zooming enabled. Put the pins as `UIButton` instances on top of your map image. `MKMapview` is **NOT** what you need here. `MKMapView` = Google/Apple Maps.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you post some code that you are playing around with - what have you tested so far. assuming you are doing your first steps in Objective-C and Cocoa touch I suggest you spend few hours watching generic tutorials such as http://itunes.apple.com/gb/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255